# Moderator ask for answer edit and do not respond

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

hi i have no response from moderators on message/10230

since Dec 11 at 22:32

please help

Because

(I cannot post an additional message until a moderator has responded)

moderator ask me to modify my answers for several question to address the specific question being asked. which i did and then ask for my account on stackoverflow to be unlock but i get no response and my answers are still deleted

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? I didn't get it.

Comment: @hims056 this might have been in response to a moderator note thingy (moderators can send out a sort of private message to users in regards to official moderator business)

Comment: yes i did respond to the private message and did what the moderator ask of me but now how to get my messages undeleted and my account active ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScript to judge, but some of the questions you answered look to me like possible duplicates.

Comment: hi bummi the first idea i had was to share a solution i found with those having the same problem which was at first sharing how i sorted out my problem but i did edit each one to address their specific problem following the moderators comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not the moderator who initially contacted you, but it looks like he missed your last response.

I've restored the answers you edited. You should be good to go now.